# What are lawful network interception tools?

Tags: network

I am looking for network interception tools, which involves sniffing external networks... this is regards to a forensic project.. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not a legal advice site.  Do not take any advice given here as legally correct.  Having said that, I believe all such tools would be legal, unless used illegally.  Much like a knife is a legal tool unless used as a weapon.  Again, saying that, software recommendations are off topic here.  What research have you done on your own?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am looking for legal usage, the problem is to sniff network traffic outside our network.

Comment: the tools will be used for lawful and legitmate activities, licensed will be preferred

Comment: In the US, "digital weapons" are legal, but merely _owning_ a panzerfaust will get you 10 years in a federal prison! Kind of strange.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the countries I am aware of, network sniffing tools themselves are legal. The law is worded such that *acts* are legal or illegal, rather than the tools that may be (mis)used to commit those acts. There slight are exceptions to this, in that *production* of tools whose sole purpose is illegal (e.g. writing malware) may also be illegal, but then it's the act of production rather than the possession of malware that is illegal.

If you're just talking about a network sniffing tool like tcpdump or Wireshark, then it's *probably* legal to possess, and likely legal to use when you have authorisation to do so on a network.

That being said, I'm not a lawyer, and I only have a limited experience of the law in the UK and USA. If you're concerned, contact a legal professional in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Possession of laws malware could get interesting.

Comment: @GriffinNowak Possession of malware by itself, for the mostpart, in jurisdictions I am aware of, is entirely legal. Consider a case where someone is infected by malware; the computer is their property and therefore they are in possession of malware. If simple possession was illegal, then they would be, which makes no sense. The interesting (and muddy) parts of law are the parts that separate incidental possession from possession with intent.

Comment: Exactly what I was so amused by.